# Why for gcc 'UNIX' and 'unix' macros are not the same thing?

Tags: c++, c, go, unix, gcc

I have a weird problem with gcc in Ubuntu Mate.

I need to write a golang program which uses a third-party C library, but i'v run a problem.

When I try to connect the third-party library in this code:

```
package main

// #cgo CFLAGS: -I /opt/cprocsp/include/interfaces/
// #cgo CFLAGS: -I /opt/cprocsp/include/
// #cgo CFLAGS: -I /opt/cprocsp/include/cpcsp/
// #include <stddef.h>
// #include "wincspc.h"
// #include "wincspc_int.h"
import "C"

func main() {
  var CSPConfig C.CPC_CONFIG
  C.CPCGetDefaultConfig(&CSPConfig, nil)
  CSPConfig.logConfig.name = string(C.MODNAME)
}
```

I get a compile error:

```
In file included from /opt/cprocsp/include/cpcsp/wincspc.h:28:0,
                 from ./gost.go:7:
/opt/cprocsp/include/cpcsp/WinCryptEx.h:35:10: fatal error: wincrypt.h: No such file or directory
 #include <wincrypt.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I didn't know what this error meant. Next I decided to open WinCryptEx.h and I found these lines there:

```
#if defined UNIX || defined CSP_LITE
#include "CSP_WinCrypt.h"
#else // UNIX
#include <wincrypt.h>
#endif // UNIX
```

So I realized that the compiler runs else statement (but I want it runs if statement because my OS is Linux). To confirm the problem I decided to write a C sample.

```
#if defined UNIX
#include "CSP_WinCrypt.h"
#else 
#include <wincrypt.h>
#endif 

int main()
{
    printf("Hello world");
}
```

When I try to run this sample, I get the same error.
But then I decided to try to run the next code:

```
#if defined unix
#include "CSP_WinCrypt.h"
#else 
#include <wincrypt.h>
#endif 

int main()
{
    printf("Hello world");
}
```

And it works fine!! The compiler runs if statement as I need.
I don't understand why.

I can't change the third-party library. So I need the compiler work correctly with 'UNIX' macro.

Does anyone have a solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Re "*I don't understand why.*", Really? The concept of case-sensitivity should be quite familiar to someone using unix. Ever try to use `PrintF` instead of `printf`?

Comment: Anyway, at the very least, you could use `#define UNIX`, or `-DUNIX` on `gcc`'s command-line

Comment: "Why for GGC 'UNIX' and 'unix' macros are not the same thing?" - Well, one is upper case and the other is not. Why would you expect them to be equal?

Comment: The `UNIX` word must be defined in the command line used for compilation or by `#define UNIX` somewhere before `#if defined UNIX`

Comment: @Ripi2 yeah. I've added #if define UNIX and now it works. It's a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This query to a popular Internet search engine](https://www.google.com/search?q=UNIX+site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fgcc.gnu.org%2Fonlinedocs%2Fcpp%2F) brings only a single page matching the word "unix" in the proper context: it's [this page on system-specific macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/System-specific-Predefined-Macros.html#System-specific-Predefined-Macros).

That page hints at two things:

- GCC does not guarantee that `UNIX` macro is defined.
- The `unix` macro is described as being "common" but nothing is
  stated about the fact it has to be present:

  > However, historically system-specific macros have had names with no special prefix; for instance, it is common to find `unix` defined on Unix systems. For all such macros, GCC provides a parallel macro with two underscores added at the beginning and the end. If `unix` is defined, `__unix__` will be defined too.

In either case, identifiers in C are case-sensitive, and so are the symbols handled by its preprocessor, so `unix` and `UNIX` are two unrelated symbols.

In your case, I would supposedly reverse the logic and test for Windows, not the other way.
There, the symbol `_WIN32` should be defined by both MinGW and MSVC.